# How to dynamically add a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, layout, user-interface

Hello I want to have a table of `UILabel`. The first column is the name of an item and the second is the value of that item. The problem is I don't know how many rows I need until the user logins in. I know how to add rows to a table in Android however it seems impossible to do with the iPhone. How would I achieve this?

[image: View]

Comment: This is a UITableView in iPhone. See the docs.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a UITableView with custom cells.

The advantage is that, depending on your data source, a table view can automatically update when your data changes. An event-driven architecture (ie: update table when data is available/changes) is in-line with objective-c land.

For examples of custom cells: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

For tutorials on making a UITableView backed by a data source, I'd point you to the excellent Stanford iOS programming course, available on iTunes U.

Answer (score 1):

There is a view called UITableView special for these aims. Read this article:

[Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

[UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the UITableViewDataSource protocol.  In this case, one method of the protocol is this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [myData count];
}
```

You can see the entire protocol documentation here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two different ways.

In the first one you can create labels programatically. A label (`UILabel` class) inherits from `UIView`. So, if you have a superview, you can add labels on it depending on user login. You have to position labels using the `frame` property. For example:

```
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 40, 300, 50)];
titlelabel.text = @"title";
[ySursuperview addSubview:titleLabel];
[titleLabel release];

// add labels here
```

In the second case you could use a `UITableView` (that contains an header view for the title) and a where each `UITableViewCell` contains NameX and ValueX. You could use also a custom `UITableViewCell`.

In my opinion the second solution could be more elegant and easier to maintain. The first one, instead, is more quickly but you have to do some calculations to obtain the grid layout you want.